# Swift. Can't use Type variable as specification to generic method

Tags: swift, generics

I try to make a generic method in Swift without an object of a generic type with this code:

```swift
protocol TestProtocol {}

class TestClass1: TestProtocol {}
class TestClass2: TestProtocol {}
class TestClass3: TestProtocol {}
class TestClass4: TestProtocol {}

enum TestEnum {
    case one, two, three, four
    
    var type: TestProtocol.Type {
        switch self {
        case .one: return TestClass1.self
        case .two: return TestClass2.self
        case .three: return TestClass3.self
        case .four: return TestClass4.self
        }
    }
}

class TestMethods {
    func prepareToGet(kind: TestEnum) {
        getTest(as: kind.type)
    }
    
    func getTest<TestType: TestProtocol>(as: TestType.Type) {
      // here I need specified type of TestProtocol to handle it
    }
}
```

But with Type variable. But I have errors:

`Cannot convert value of type 'TestProtocol.Type' to expected argument type 'TestType.Type'`

`Generic parameter 'TestType' could not be inferred`

I feel blind, but I really don't see the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use `TestProtocol.Type` instead of `TestType.Type`, i.e.

```
func getTest(as type: TestProtocol.Type) {}
```

Comment: Oh, I see my question was not so clear. It's just a test code to show my issue. In getTest I need specified type of TestProtocol to handle it

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that you want the function to know the class of the generic by using information from the enum, but generic functions need to be able to infer the type at compile time, and the result of `TestEnum.type` is only available at run time.

I'm not sure what the real case scenario you have, but I think that the best you can do is to have a function that returns `TestProtocol`, either as a type or object, whatever you need, and conditionally cast it to the type you want.

If you give us a more real-life example, we might be able to help you find a better solution.

Comment: The case is receiving a response with a few types of nested objects. And I needed to specify which one I need in every case. But with your clarification about compile time I see, that it's impossible. Thank you for your answer